# Show popup under specific asp control

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working with a textbox in ASP.NET and I added a JavaScript that pop up Calendar control on "OnClick" event (I am using window.open() to open the popup).  Is there any way I could show the popup right under the textbox?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using window.open?  Have you looked into jQuery using a a DIV popup?

You can also use jQuery to find the location of your textbox and place the popup near the X,y offset of you textbox.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
download the jquery and jquery ui
```

add the jquery and jqueryui  reference to the asp.net project

insert this code in script tag

```
 $(document).ready( function()


  {
   $("input[id$='txt_Date']").datepicker();
});
```

when you click the textbox it will show the calendar.